# HOW TO FIND DUPLICATE RECORDS IN SQL

Tags: sql

table:

```
ID      status    CREATED TIME
OD01    CLOSED    12-09-2020
OD01    OPEN      10-09-2020
OD02    CLOSED    09-09-2020
OD02    CLOSED    07-09-2020
OD03    OPEN      04-09-2020
OD03    OPEN      06-09-2020
```

I WANT OUTPUT as ID IS SAME AND BOTH THE SHOULD BE CLOSED

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Please **DO NOT** write in **ALL CAPS** - it's really annoyingly hard to read, and it's generally considered **SHOUTING** at your readers - which is just plain rude and offensive - fix your post ASAP, please

Comment: Sample data is great, but the expected result is also needed.

Comment: Please take some time to frame the question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having sum(case when status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) >= 2
```

or

```
select id
from your_table
where status = 'closed'
group by id
having count(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select id from tablename
group by id 
having max(status)='closed' and min(status)='closed'
```

OR Alternatively you can try this too - using `not exists`

```
select distinct id from tablename t 
 where not exists (select 1 from tablename t1 where t.id=t1.id and status='open')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I WANT OUTPUT as ID IS SAME AND BOTH THE SHOULD BE CLOSED

I interpret this as:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(*) = 2 and                -- exactly two rows
       min(status) = max(status) and   -- status values are the same
       min(status) = 'closed';         -- the one status value is closed
```